# How to restrict single word (that itselft having only string not number) while entering value in inputbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Im using this code to restrict the user to not enter special characters

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
         var text=$(this).val();
         $(this).val(text.replace(/[^\w\d\s]/,""));
    })
```

I want to restrict the user to enter only one word without space and also having no numbers and special characters. like this

```
myword                #valid
myword2              #invalid
myword secondword    #invalid
```

Comment: From experience, silently replacing the input value on every `keyup` is not only inefficient, but has great potential to be irritating. My suggestion is just to perform validation on `change` (maybe have a warning show up if the input is invalid), and prevent `submit` when invalid. If I was typing in `qwerty` and accidentally type in `qwert6`, your code would change this to `qwert` without letting me know. If this was a username (or, *gasp* a password), I probably wouldn't be able to log in if I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).val(text.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g,''));
```

[Test it here »](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/k2dHP/)

Answer (score 2):

here's a jQuery plugin that will prevent typing keys that are not in the specified regex. It also works if you paste something, but that works with replace.

```
$("body").delegate("[keyfilter]", "keypress", function(event) {
    var elem = $(this), filter = elem.attr('keyfilter');
    if (event.charCode === 0) {
      return;
    }
    try {
        if (!String.fromCharCode(event.charCode).match(new RegExp("[" + filter + "]"))) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
    } catch(e) {}
}).delegate("[keyfilter]", "paste", function(event) {
    var elem = $(this), filter = elem.attr('keyfilter');
    setTimeout(function() { elem.val(elem.val().match(new RegExp("[" + filter + "]"))[0]) }, 50);
});
```

the way to use it:

```
<input type="text" keyfilter="A-Za-z" />
```

Comment: Seems @Shef 's version also handles paste, at least in Fx5

Comment: what I meant was, his `onkeyup text.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g,'')` ALSO handles paste. So I wonder what it does not handle that your plugin does since it is so much simpler and therefore should handle less browsers or situations :)

Comment: it doesn't if you use the mouse